# Как использовать переменную в исходном тексте регулярного выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Собственно такое выражение:

```
preg_match("/$a(.*?)/i",$text,$matches);
```

в одинарные ковычки не могу поместить текст, так как переменная `$a` не будет обрабатываться, а с двойными ковычками выдаёт ошибку.
Как правильно использовать переменную в исходном тексте регулярки?

Comment: Нужно использовать функцию `preg_quote()`. Вопросы на enSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936342/escaping-string-for-use-in-regular-expression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописать переменную $a в скобки функции preg_quote(), а функцию preg_quote() прописать внутри вашего шаблона, используя конкатенацию:

```
preg_match('~'. preg_quote($a, '~') .'(.*?)~i', $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
preg_match("/\\Q$a\\E(.*?)/i", $text, $matches);
```

Более подробно про \Q\E можно почитать здесь: [PCRE: Escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: Этот вариант более предпочтительней, так как быстрее чем использование функции `preg_quote()`.

Comment: Протестировал `\Q` и `\E`, почему-то не справляются с символом обозначающим границу регулярки :( В данном случае если в `$a` встретится символ `/`, `preg_match()` вернет `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант `preg_match(sprintf("/%s(.*?)/i", $a),$text,$matches);`